# How to align social media icons in one row?

Tags: css

I managed to add facebook, twitter and g +1 social media buttons to my website in one row. But when I try to add the VK like button to the same row it just goes beneath the rest.

1. I tried aligning all 4 of them by using CSS and all buttons aligned correctly while the VK button just displaced to a new row. Here is how I tried doing it:

`#Social {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;`

1. Tried using basic HTML `<center></center>` and same story first 3 buttons did align, the VK button went to a new row.

Here is the code for VK button:
`<div id="vk_like"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "button", height: 20});
</script>`

Hope you can help me sort this one out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#vk_like { display: inline-block; }` ?

Comment: Thanks. Steve's reply was correct too and maybe event a bit better, I was just too lazy to elaborate on the "why" :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's because  the VK code is wrapping your button in a `div` tag which is a block element. To fix it you must either replace the `div` with a `span` (keeping the id the same) or if that doesn't work because the JavaScript is looking explicity for a div with that id, then do as Robert suggests: style the div to be display inline-block which tells the browser to render a block element as if it were an inline element.

Comment: Oh, it actually worked perfectly with the `span` instead of `div`. Thank you for the suggestion and the thorough explanation!